# Images not showing in media library

Tags: database, wordpress, media-library

In media library not works preview images because its loaded with url "image-484x500.jpg" instead just "image.jpg"

How to force WordPress load it without -484x500 in url? I dont want regenereate thumbanils because it need a lot space in server.

What i did - I removed images in uploads folder and upload new images. But probably in database are this old links.

[image]

Comment: "I removed images in uploads folder and upload new images. But probably in database are this old links." --> This is most likely the problem! Wordpress always creates different sized versions of the images you upload to use optimized (responsive) images in every situation. Deleting them (or some of them) will get you into trouble, as you can see.

Comment: Have you changed from site url? Also, as @Johannes mentions, never upload or remove images directly to the folder, do it from the Wordpress interface.